# In R, is there a way to specify a vector as a *literal*?

Tags: r, vector, literals

[Have just started to learn R]

Say, I want to create a vector with the values `1 4 6 8`. Neither of these work:

```
x <- [1, 4, 6, 8]
x <- [1 4 6 8]
```

Is there a way to create a vector using literal notation, i.e. without using a function etc?

Comment: Not sure what's so slow about `c(1,4,6,8)` -- it's *one* extra character to type.

Comment: The answer is no. Everything you do is a function in R. What do you think `<-` is?

Comment: not sure about the downvotes.  Not much research effort, and the "why" part is a little annoying, but I think it's an interesting ("useful") question

Comment: Each language has a syntax. If you don't like R's syntax, and do like Matlab then ....  choose Matlab.

Comment: "literals" only make real sense in compiled languages. R only sees that line when it gets to it, then it has to parse it, split the RHS on the commas, get the numbers, make a vector, stick it in `x`. However you represent it (c(1,2,3) or [1,2,3]), its the same amount of work.

Comment: ^While that makes some sense to me, I am not completely convinced. Languages like java, javascript and even c# are (generally) interpreted. But they still allow and recommend the use of literals when appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your first question

> Is there a way to create a vector using literal notation, i.e. without
>   using a function etc?

you can create a vector in such a way that sort of *mimics* your example of using "literal notation" above; but technically (just about) everything in R is a function call, even bracket indexing `[` and object assignment `<-`. For example, you could do something like

```
x <- NULL
x[1:4] <- 1:4
##
> x
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

but then again `[<-` and `:` are functions - see the help file by typing `?"[<-"` or `?"["`. Whether or not this is "more awkward" than your alternative is of course subjective, but once you are accustomed to the R language you most likely won't give it a second thought. Personally I prefer it to something like `x[1, 2, 3, 4]` which you might do in Python, Julia, etc... Regardless, your first example is not valid for a `vector` because in R syntax you use (n-1) commas to represent (n) dimensions (in cases like this). For instance, you could create a 3 dimensional array like

```
Y <- array(1:27,dim=c(3,3,3))
> Y
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   22   25
[2,]   20   23   26
[3,]   21   24   27

and access elements as 

> Y[1,1,3]
[1] 19
> Y[1,1,1]
[1] 1
> Y[1,2,3]
[1] 22
```

but obviously this is not the case with (one dimensional) vectors. 
To your other point about speed, it's impossible to test this exactly because your proposed syntax is not valid.

Comment: Why do you go all the way `x1 <- NULL ; x1[1:10000] <- 1:10000` instead of just `x <- 1:10000`? Also, `:` is also a function, so how is it different than just using `c`?

Comment: It was the closest thing I could come up with to replicate his `x <- [1,2,3,4]` type syntax; I certainly would just use `x <- 1:10000` in my own code. Also, I noted that `:` is a function as well - and as you pointed out above there is not way to avoid using some type of function. I'm not really saying they're different, I was just trying to come up with something that resembles his comparison of using `c(...)` vs. `[...]`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to create a list and then convert it to a vector like this:

```
x <- unlist(list(1,4,6,8))
```